# K4S561632 SDRAM memory size

Tags: embedded

I'm using K4S561632C 256Mbit SDRAM for increasing MCU's memory, but I found these lines in the SDRAM's initialing library which deliver the product:

```
#define SDRAM_BASE_ADDR     0xA0000000
#define SDRAM_SIZE          0x01000000   /* 16M 128Mbit 1024*1024*16 byte */
```

but as I said above it is 256Mbit memory while SDRAM_Size refers to 128 Mbit memory. Can anyone please clear this up for me?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Question is clear,Why we declare 128Mbit memory size while it has 256Mbit size?

Comment: You are of course expected to modify the SDRAM controller initialisation code to match the device you are using - and probably not only the size - the timing is critical too.  You'd be more likely to get useful help if you specified what MCU you were using, and indicate where the code you are referring to has come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible answers, depending on the code in the library you are using.

**Possibility 1**:

According to the K4S561632C data sheet, the device is a 4M x 16bit x 4 Banks SDRAM. Since its data bus is 16 bits wide (2 bytes), that means there are 4M x 4 = 16,777,216 (0x1000000) distinct addresses, with a 16-bit value at each address. The `SDRAM_SIZE` value in the library is referring to the number of 16-bit words, not the number of bytes, in the device.

**Possibility 2**:

The library file is wrong.  Perhaps it originally referred to an earlier 128Mbit part, and when the newer 256Mbit part was introduced, the library vendor did not update their library to agree with the new part. If this is the case, then you may wish to change the line as follows:

```
#define SDRAM_SIZE          0x02000000
```